# How to hide build text in Visual Studio 2013 Express output window?

Tags: window, output

When I compile my file in Visual Studio, I find it very hard to read what went wrong and where. I don't like seeing this huge text when all I really need to see is that I have a misprinted character somewhere.
[image: tons of text]

In Code::Blocks, its nice and clean
[image: nice and clean]

In the 'Show output from:' drop-down, 'Build' is the only option.
Is there any way to hide all of those configuration texts ? Or splitting up the error message in tabs, like in Code::Blocks and other IDE's, so that I can hide the directory, etc. I've been snooping around the settings and searching the web but nothing provided.

EDIT: got it. Thanks to Roman Mik for his comment and another user on SO who said:

> Go to Tools, Options, Projects And Solutions, and uncheck Show Output
>   Window when Build Starts.

Comment: You may want to use Error List instead of output. The Error List will show your errors instead of everything that happened before. View > Error List

Comment: Okay! this worked, now how do I make this my default windows when I build? I still get the output window by default. I'd like to hide the output window altogether